# Notification sound is not created when phone is locked

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing a chat application and I am using Firebase Cloud Messaging. Notification works properly. When the phone is locked, the notification is received properly, but the sound is not generated.

Any help is appreciated.

FCMMessagingservice.java

```
package com.synergywebdesigners.nima;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import static android.app.Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC;
import static com.android.volley.VolleyLog.TAG;


/**
 * Created by Ashish Shahi on 13-04-2017.
 */

public class FcmMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500};
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)getSystemService(
                Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
                PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK
                        | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,
                TAG);


        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String message = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Memberlist.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_action_title)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(0)
                .setLights(Color.RED, 500, 500)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setOngoing(true)
                ;
        wl.acquire();
        // ... do work...
        wl.release();
        /*notificationBuilder.setLights(Color.BLUE, 500, 500);
        long[] pattern = {500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500,500};
        notificationBuilder.setVibrate(pattern);*/
        notificationBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle());
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question properly, you are not getting notification tone when phone is locked. Well FCM provides 2 ways to push notification on devices. One works when your app is in foreground and the other when it's in background and you might have to handle both the cases. Please check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

Comment: Please say me how can i fix this problem

Comment: Edit out your post with the latest codes and also post the error logs so I could see what's happening.

Comment: Not sure where the downvote came from and why, but decided to just remove my answer. I would still suggest you put in the error logs that you encountered after trying out a `data`-only message payload. Good luck.

Comment: You Give me write answer. But Not Misguide me ..

Comment: I was guiding you by asking some additional details, but there wasn't any. That's not really a reason to downvote an answer, but all's cool. Cheers!

Comment: @Al sir i am not give you downward reward any Other Person Giving You Downward reward

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141877/discussion-between-ashish-and-al).

Comment: I am solve this Problem

Answer (score 0):

Go to FCM CONSOLE and enable sound and  define key 'sound'==>'default';
and go to php cansole and and type Following code  `'sound'==>'default';` thats work properly

Comment: thanks For This idea But only One Problem when i am use api level 16 phone context.message doesn't show please help me Thank in Advance.